# Prove equation with binomial coefficient

Tags: binomial-theorem

Prove $$\sum_{k=0}^s{\frac{\binom{s}{k}}{\binom{t}{r+k}}} = \frac{t+1}{(t+1-s)\binom{t-s}{r}} $$
for  $r + s \le t$

Answer (score 3):

We can apply the *[beta function identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)*
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{k}^{-1}=(n+1)\int_0^1x^k(1-x)^{n-k}\,dx
\end{align*}
We start with the left hand side using this identity and then rearrange it and apply the binomial theorem. The right hand side follows.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^s}&\color{blue}{\binom{s}{k}\binom{t}{r+k}^{-1}}\\&=\sum_{k=0}^s\binom{s}{k}(t+1)\int_0^1x^{r+k}(1-x)^{t-r-k}\,dx\\
> &=(t+1)\int_{0}^1x^r(1-x)^{t-r}\sum_{k=0}^s\binom{s}{k}\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^k\,dx\\
> &=(t+1)\int_{0}^1x^r(1-x)^{t-r}\left(1+\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^s\,dx\\
> &=(t+1)\int_0^1x^r(1-x)^{t-s-r}\,dx\\
> &\color{blue}{=\frac{t+1}{t-s+1}\binom{t-s}{r}^{-1}}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

Comment: As always: well explained. ;)

Comment: @user90369: Thanks for your nice comment and the credit. :-)

Comment: Nothing to thank, you have (in my opinion) just a really good explanatory style. ;)